# Grails 1.3.7 doesn't inject logger in domain

Tags: grails

According to official document says: 
"There are two main ways to get hold of a logger:
  1.use the log instance injected into artifacts such as domain classes, controllers and services;"

So we have this code in the domain:

```
def afterInsert() {
    if(this.keys){
        log.info("ImageRecords insert success")
    }else{
        log.info("ImageRecords insert fails")
    }
}
```

But when the save() method is called, I got the following exception messages:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: log for class: org.my.application.ImageRecords
Possible solutions: id, dup
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:49)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoMetaClassGetPropertySite.java:50)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:239)
at org.my.application.ImageRecords.afterInsert(CdImageBarcodeRecords.groovy:88)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:186)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:171)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventListener$MethodCaller.call(ClosureEventListener.java:302)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventListener.onPostInsert(ClosureEventListener.java:227)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.onPostInsert(ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.java:160)
at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.postInsert(EntityInsertAction.java:149)
at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:128)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:279)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:263)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:167)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.events.PatchedDefaultFlushEventListener.performExecutions(PatchedDefaultFlushEventListener.java:46)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1027)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:365)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:656)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
......
```

Do I miss some settings?

Comment: That should have worked ootb. Have you tried restarting the app or `clean` and then restarting?

Comment: Yes, I have tried clean and restart the app, but it still gave me the missing property exception.

Comment: 1.3.7???? Time to upgrade.

Comment: I hope I could. Since that's a project of my company, I can't upgrade it. I just comment out the code about logging right now, and hope there are some solutions, or figure out what would causes this situation at least.

Comment: Where is your domain class located? is it in the 'domain' folder or the 'src' folder ?

Comment: I put it in the "domain" folder.